# Fail Deploy the Java Web Project using Docker [no main manifest attribute]

Tags: java, spring-mvc, docker

I am building a website using Spring  MVC. Now I am trying to deploy the project using Docker. By deploying the jar file.

I have try this in my terminal:

```
sudo docker build -t springmvc:1.0 .
```

And this is the result:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  44.25MB
Step 1/3 : FROM java:8
 ---> d23bdf5b1b1b
Step 2/3 : COPY mavenspringmvc.jar /home/mavenspringmvc.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d82a8a4083b2
Step 3/3 : CMD ["java", "-jar", "/home/mavenspringmvc.jar"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 280a69737e48
Successfully built 280a69737e48
Successfully tagged springmvc:1.0
```

And this is the content of Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
COPY mavenspringmvc.jar /home/mavenspringmvc.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/home/mavenspringmvc.jar"]
```

I tried this syntax:

```
sudo docker run -it -p8080:8080 springmvc:1.0
```

And the error appeared:

```
no main manifest attribute, in /home/mavenspringmvc.jar
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.converter</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-springmvc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>maven-springmvc Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!--dependency-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--j2ee, servlet、jsp、jstl-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--mysql-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--springframework-->
    <!-- Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--apache.commons-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Servlet-Api -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--additional for uplaod-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- File Upload Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>maven-springmvc</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.converter</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>docker-build</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
      <!--Said that the java directory under the relevant xml file, properties file compile / package when placed in the resource directory-->
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!--Servlet container jetty plugin-->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>9.3.10.v20160621</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <executable>false</executable>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

The question is how to solve this problem? So that, I can deploy the project using Docker?

Comment: Does it work without docker?

Comment: Yes it work well when i click run button in intelij

Comment: But does it work if you execute `java -jar mavenspringmvc.jar` outside docker and outside your IDE?